# sparklyr: Cannot Open Local Connection | Permission Denied

Tags: r, windows, apache-spark, sparklyr

I have been trying to run a local instance of Spark on my Windows 10 laptop from RStudio but without success. I get the following error promt:

```
* Using Spark: 2.3.0
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Temp\*******\********_spark.log': Permission denied
```

I have tried all suggested solutions I have found online, including installing sparklyr from github, running R and RStudio as an administrator, running only 64 Bit java, and checking that all .cmd files have the correct permissions. Still, the connection fails.

The commands I run to launch Spark are straightforward:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
```

This is the prompt from session.info:

Session info

```
setting  value                       
version  R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
os       Windows >= 8 x64            
system   x86_64, mingw32             
ui       RStudio                     
language EN                          
collate  German_Austria.1252         
ctype    German_Austria.1252         
tz       Europe/Berlin               
date     2019-02-12
```

sparklyr   -  0.9.9006 2019-02-12 [1] Github (rstudio/sparklyr@6b41c4a)

---

I'm very thankful for any help!

Comment: I had the same problem, which went away after updating the value of `HADOOP_HOME` like this: `Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME='C:/Users/****/AppData/Local/spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/tmp/hadoop')`